# How do you make a div go under another div/nav menu which is not fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div go under another div in which neither are fixed elements.

Here is my code:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {

}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li.dropdown {

}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #4CAF50;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #4CAF50;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #4CAF50;}

ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  ul.topnav li.right,
  ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
#white {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90%;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Creations</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Photos</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn" href="#news">Events</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#1">DIY</a>
      <a href="#2">Flea Market Flip</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">Recycle + Upcycle</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Saving The Enviroment</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="white"></div>
```

I need to be able to make my drop down menu appear over the div named #white. Another note, my links currently lead nowhere, so they are useless right now.

Comment: Have you tried z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have css property `overflow:hidden` in your `ul.topnav` and need to remove that to show the drop-down menu. Also I added `z-index` values to `ul.topnav` and `#white` so that menu go over the div.

```
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
  #white {
    background-color: white;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5zgne9b/). Hope this helps you.